# Scala/Java Error handling a NullPointerException

Tags: java, scala, error-handling, nullpointerexception, try-catch

I am working on a method which gets elements out of a double linked deque. When the linkedlist is empty, I get a nullpointerexception and I am trying to figure out how to handle it. I am using to following code but it still requires me to return A. Any ideas how I can get to this compile?

```
def peekBack():A = {
  try {
    last.data // return if the list is full if not, catch the nullpointerexception
  } catch {
    case ex: NullPointerException => {
      println("There are no elements in this list.")
         //Error is here, it is requiring me to return something!!!
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: return null from the catch block

Comment: I tried that but it gave me a type mismatch

Comment: is Data in the deque of primitive type or an Object ?

Comment: class LinkedDeQue[A] extends Deque[A]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `last` is some `var` that ends up being `null` at some point, what about a simple if:

```
def peekBack(): A = {
  if (last == null) 
    throw new NoSuchElementException("empty list")
  else last.data
}
```

**Edit**: if you do want to return `null`, you need a proof that `A` is nullable:

```
def peekBack()(implicit ev: Null <:< A): A = {
  if (last == null) ev(null)
  else last.data
}
```

Of course the proper way to do this would be to return an `Option[A]`:

```
def peekBack(): Option[A] = Option(last).map(_.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont take a nullpointerexception when your list is empty. you take it when your object is not initialized. ensure that you call a "initialized" empty object or best, foresee that also in your method

Comment: My list is empty when last = null.